# Json InvalidFormatException : Cannot deserialize value of type HandType from String "flush"

Tags: java, json

I am having some issues with the deserialization of a Json to a Java object.
My Json looks like this:

```
"players": [
       {
         "id": "12345678",
         "handtype": "flush"
       },
       {
         "id": "12345679",
         "handtype": "straight"
       }
     ]
```

My Java classes look like this:

```
public class Players {

   @JsonProperty(value = "id")
   private String id;

   @JsonProperty(value = "handtype")
   private HandType handType;

   public String getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public void setHandType(HandType handType) {
       this.handType = handType;
   }

   public HandType getHandType() {
       return handType;
   }
```

```
public enum HandType {
       HIGH_CARD("high_card"),
       PAIR("pair"),
       TWO_PAIRS("two_pairs"),
       THREE_OF_A_KIND("three_of_a_kind"),
       STRAIGHT("straight"),
       FLUSH("flush"),
       FULL_HOUSE("full_house"),
       FOUR_OF_A_KIND("four_of_a_kind"),
       STRAIGHTFLUSH("straightflush"),
       ROYALFLUSH("royalflush");

       private String handName;

   HandType(String handName) {
       this.handName = handName;
   }

   public String getHandName() {
       return handName;
   }
}
```

What seems to be wrong is that it expects "FLUSH", but I give him "flush" - although I have in the enum the Strings which should match the lowercase scenario.
How should I write my code in order to get rid of the exceptions ?

Answer (score 1):

First, your `players` is a `List<Player>`, not a `Players`:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "players")
List<Player> players;
```

So each `Player` would look like this (note I made the properties `final`, I don't think you actually want them to be mutable once the object is initialized):

```
public class Player {
    
   @JsonProperty(value = "id")
   private final String id;

   @JsonProperty(value = "handtype")
   private final HandType handType;

   @JsonCreator
   public Player(@JsonProperty(value = "id") String id, @JsonProperty(value = "handtype") HandType handType) {
       this.id = id;
       this.handType = handType;
   }

}
```

And to conclude, the getter in your enum should be annotated by `@JsonValue` in order to tell Jackson where to get the string value of the enum (else, by default, Jackson will try to de-serialize the enum by its `.toString()` representation which in your case is `FLUSH`, not `flush`):

```
@JsonValue
public String getHandName() {
    return handName;
}
```